# Order infinite scroll posts in django

Tags: python, django

I  experience hard time trying to implement infinite scrolling feature :(. The problem is that it orders posts in the wrong way. For example, if I have posts 1 2 3 4 5 it orders them in the following order: 1 3 4 5 2. And if I try to reverse order them it does 5 3 2 1 4. For some reason it puts second element in the end.
It's very strange and I have no clue why it is so.

Here's my view finction:

```
class index(ListView):

    model = Post
    template_name = "index.html"
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 2
    ordering = ['pub_date']
```

Template:

```
{% for post in posts %}

<div class="infinite-container">
    <div class="infinite-item">
        {{ post.author.first_name }}
        {{ post.description }}
    </div>
</div>

{% endfor %}

{% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" class="infinite-more-link"></a>
{% endif %}

<script>
    var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
        element: $('.infinite-container')[0],
        offset: 'bottom-in-view',
    });
</script>
```

Also when I change value of paginate_by to 3 it does 1 4 5 2 3

Answer (score 0):

I was so dumb. The problem is that for loop needs to be inside the inifinite-container...